# Активация input type="date" при наведении

Tags: javascript, input

```html
<body>

  <label for="calendar" id="dater"> 
    Choose date before continue:  <input type="date" id="calendar">
</label>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('dater').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      document.getElementById('calendar').click();
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Не нашел информации почему не срабатывает 'mouseover' при наведении на input[type="date"] при имитации его методом 'click()'?

Answer (score 3):

Все срабатывает:

```html
<label for="calendar" id="dater"> 
  Choose date before continue:  <input type="date" id="calendar" onclick="console.log('in onclick')">
</label>

<script>
  document.getElementById('dater').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('in mouseover');
    document.getElementById('calendar').click();
  })
</script>
```

Или Вам нужен фокус?

```html
<label for="calendar" id="dater"> 
  Choose date before continue:  <input type="date" id="calendar" onfocus="console.log('in onfocus')">
</label>

<script>
  document.getElementById('dater').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('in mouseover');
    document.getElementById('calendar').focus();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Igor, прошу прощения,  а вы каким браузером пользуетесь?  
у меня не в Edge, не в  Firefox, не в Blisk,  не в  Safari не работает (((  в лучшем случае выделяет (фокусирует) но сам календарь не открывается. не получается такого результата, как если бы я просто кликнул по  input

Comment: А в Хроме календарь и не появляется по клику. Только если иконку кликать.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что не `click`, а `focus`, но подсовывать пользователю такое поведение - это свинство.

```js
document.getElementById('dater').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.getElementById('calendar').focus();
})
```

```html
<label for="calendar" id="dater"> 
  Choose date before continue:  <input type="date" id="calendar">
</label>
```

Comment: а можно обосновать без лишней эмоциональной оценки - просто факты?

Comment: а можно не минусовать правильные ответы?

Comment: не знаю,  я вообще не очень люблю общаться с хамами и заносчивыми типами, которые от черезмерно завышенного самомнения дерзять новичкам, строя из себя всеосознанных "гуру". Вас спросили по челочечески - не переходя на личности. Вы же вместо ответа (исходя из контекста можно понять что человек в лучшем случае "junior" в худшем вообще начинающий), начали дерзить без объяснения причины!  А на ризонный вопрос по поводу фактического ответа, стали отвечать вопросом на вопрос...  Думаю нет нельзя!